# What is the best method for catching all exceptions in a ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

Where is the best place to catch exceptions in an old .NET 4.8 Web Forms application that aren't manually being caught and handled already?

I am currently using `Airbrake`, and they provide an ASP.NET module to do this however, it relies on credentials existing within `web.config` which is something I cannot make use of.

Looking at other tools such as elmah, it would appear their [module](https://github.com/elmah/Elmah/blob/master/src/Elmah.AspNet/ErrorLogModule.cs#L42) hooks into `HttpModuleBase` and `IExceptionFiltering` automatically catching exceptions, how would one go about manually doing this?

I am guessing one of the events with Global.asax but not too sure where to begin.

(updating beyond 4.8 / non `Web Forms` isn't an option at the moment)

Comment: You saw the Application_Error event in global.asax? That'd be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with mason:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Insert error handling code here
    }
}
```

This is part of the Global class that is created within you global.asax file.